# How do i graph this piecewise function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
 -3 & \text{ if } x < 1 \\ 
x + 1 & \text{ if } 1 \le x \le 3 \\
4 & \text{ if } x > 3
\end{array}\right.$$

Maybe the better question would be how do I solve for $x$ so I can graph the function? I don't know what $x$ equals to plot the specific points. 
Here's an image of my graph is it correct?
[image: graph]

Comment: It is just a piecewise linear function. Just plot each part as you would normally plot a straight line. You do not need to solve for $x$. By the way you should not attach an image of your question, rather you should type out the function.

Comment: If 90% of your question is an image, **please** make an effort to rotate it in a reasonable direction.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **piecewise function.** The picture will be different based on the values of $x$ tossed into the function. For example, when $x=0$, the function will assume the value $3$. If $x=2$, the function will also assume the value $3$.

To plot this function you should graph each piece on the domain specified, all on the same plane. A Google search for piecewise functions will show you more examples.

Comment: So how many different values should I plug in for x?

Answer (score 0):

The graph of this function has three parts.i.e. three straight lines .here you need not solve for x. you can draw the graph by inspection.

Answer (score 0):

We are given the piecewise-defined function 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
-3 && \text{if $x < 1$}\\
x + 1 && \text{if $1 \leq x \leq 3$}\\
4 && \text{if $x > 3$}
\end{cases}
$$
The graph of $y = -3$ is a horizontal line.  The restriction $x < 1$ means we draw the ray starting at $(1, -3)$ pointing to the left.  Since the inequality is strict, we do not include the endpoint.  This is indicated on the graph by placing an open circle at the point $(1, -3)$.

The graph of $y = 4$ is also a horizontal line.  The restriction $x > 3$ means we draw the ray starting at $(3, 4)$ pointing to the right.  Since the inequality is strict, we do not include the endpoint.  This is indicated on the graph by placing an open circle at the point $(3, 4)$.

The graph of $y = x + 1$ is a line with slope $1$ and $y$-intercept $1$.  The restriction $1 \leq x \leq 3$ means we draw the segment with endpoints $(1, f(1)) = (1, 1 + 1) = (1, 2)$ and $(3, f(3)) = (3, 3 + 1) = (3, 4)$.  Since the inequalities are weak, we include both endpoints, indicated on the graph by filled circles at the points $(1, 2)$ and $(3, 4)$.  Note that the requirement that we fill the circle at $(3, 4)$ means we fill the previously open circle at that point.

[image: piecewise-defined_function_graph]